# How can I set a custom field based on membership in a smart group?

Tags: hooks, developer, smartgroups

I want to generate membership cards based on a person's geographical region.  The region logic is fairly complex (e.g. "Anyone in NY, plus New Jersey north of Trenton and Connecticut west of Stamford").  I have smart groups that accurately place someone by region.

Before we used smart groups, we manually added folks to static groups based on region. An extension called `civicrm_post` on the GroupContact to set the custom field.  However, `civicrm_post` isn't called on smart groups.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I don't mind using SQL in a cron job, but I'm not sure that `civicrm_group_contact_cache` is reliably filled with the correct data - in older versions of Civi at least, I often found it empty.

This is Civi 4.6.10, Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

In your own cron job you could reload the cache for groups by calling civicrm_api3_job_group_rebuild() (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Job.php#L629), then cycle through the group to fill your custom field.

Comment: Brilliant, Joe.  This work is scheduled for a couple of weeks from now, I'll mark it accepted assuming this works!